# Get right array key(s) with PHP/MySQL search of joint tables

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic-arrays

I have two tables:

1st table (t1):

```
item_no | item_desc
-------------
200  | d1  
250  | d2 
257  | d3 
305  | d4  
605  | d5
606  | d6
```

2nd table (t2)

```
id | item_no | item_value
-------------
1 | 200  | v1_200  
1 | 250  | v1_250 
1 | 257  | v1_257 
1 | 305  | v1_305
1 | 605  | v1_605  
1 | 606  | v1_606
2 | 200  | v2_200  
2 | 250  | v2_250 
2 | 257  | v2_257 
2 | 305  | v2_305  
2 | 606  | v2_606
```

I get the value of the id field in t2 via $id= $_POST['id']; and do the security checks on it, etc.

I perform a join search of both tables with a query like this:

```
$items= array();
$items_no = array('200', '250', '257', '305', '605', '606');
$items_nos = implode(",", $nutrient_no);

$sql = "SELECT item_value FROM t1 join t2 ON  t1.item_no=t2.item_no WHERE t1.id='$id' AND t2.item_no in ($items_nos)";
```

Finally, I extract the results like this:

```
$retval = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
{
$item_value[] = $row['item_value'];
$first_item = $item_value['0'];
$second_item = $item_value['1'];
....
$last_item = $item_value['5'];    
}
```

Problem is, for searches on id # 2, as illustrated in the example I gave above, item_no 605 does not exist. The search still works fine, but the array keys are no longer right, i.e. $last_item's value is not returned properly because the key is now 4 instead of 5.

IMPORTANT: depending on the id used in search, none, one or more rows may be missing in the results.

I have tried this as a solution:

```
$items_count = count($item_value);
for( $x = 1; $x <= $items_count ; $x++ ) {
$foo = 'item_value' . $x;
if ( isset( $$item_value[$x-1])) {
    $$foo = $$item_value[$x-1];
}
else {
    $$foo = '';
}
$last_item = $foo['5']; 
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this? Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's strange to me to have a variable number of variables depending on a query result... but you could try something like that:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($arr)-1; $i++) { 
    ${"item_n" . $i} = $arr[$i];
}
```

And for the last item:

```
$last_item = end(array_values($arr));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @jolmos. I should clarify that, depending on the id used in search, none, one or more rows may be missing in the results, which means other items, not just he last, can be affected. How would you write your solution for such a case?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... 
With the code I wrote, you will finally have a set of vars like $item_n0=value, $item_n1=value (regardless the size of the original array or query result)... and then $lastItem = value, corresponding to the last value in the original array/query result.

Comment: Thanks again for the comment.